# Liquid Markup {% break %} out of a for loop when the value of a counter variable reaches a certain number

Tags: liquid, markup

I am quite new here so please try not to bash me too hard :D

I have the following code in LM:

```
   {% assign count = 0 %}
      {% for insight in contact.insight.Webinisights %}
      {% for page_viewed in insight.page_viewed %}
      {% if page_viewed.custom_page_values.studyTitle != null and page_viewed.custom_page_values.studyTitle != '' %}
      {% assign count = count | plus: 1 %}


          {{ page_viewed.custom_page_values.studyTitle }}
          {{ page_viewed.custom_page_values.studyDescription | append: "..." }}

      {% if count == 2 %}
      {% break %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

The idea behind is that once someone has viewed a certain page for which studyTitle !=null and studyTitle != ' ', I would like to display the title and description of that page. This works. The counter also works, but I cannot seem to figure out how to break out of the loop once the count reaches 2 instead it just keeps on going.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% assign count = 0 %}
{% for insight in contact.insight.Webinisights %}
  {% for page_viewed in insight.page_viewed %}
    {% if page_viewed.custom_page_values.studyTitle != null and page_viewed.custom_page_values.studyTitle != '' %}
    {% assign count = count | plus: 1 %}

        {{ page_viewed.custom_page_values.studyTitle }}
        {{ page_viewed.custom_page_values.studyDescription | append: "..." }}

    {% endif %}
    {% if count > 2 %}
    {% break %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,

I've managed to find a solution in the meanwhile.

```
{% assign mainLoop =  true %}
{% assign count = 0 %}
{% for insight in contact.insight.Webinsight %}
      {% for page_viewed in insight.page_viewed %}
      {% if page_viewed.custom_page_values.studyTitle != null and page_viewed.custom_page_values.studyTitle != ''%}
          {%increment count %}


{{ page_viewed.custom_page_values.studyTitle }}
{{ page_viewed.custom_page_values.studyDescription | append: "..." }}


{% endif %}
{% if count < 2 %}
{% assign mainLoop = false %}

{% break %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% unless mainLoop %}{% break %}{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```